# What additional overheads are there to sending a packet over a websocket connection?

Tags: websocket, packet, data-transfer

When performing AJAX requests, I have always tried to do as few as possible since there is an overhead to each request having to open the http connection to send the data. Since a websocket connection is constantly open, is there any cost outside of the obvious packet bandwidth to sending a request?

For example. Over the space of 1 minute, a client will send 100kb of data to the server. Assuming the client does not need a response to any of these requests, is there any advantage to queuing packets and sending them in one big burst vs sending them as they are ready?

In other words, is there an overhead to the stopping and starting data transfer for a connection that is constantly open?

I want to make a multiplayer browser game as real time as possible, but I don't want to find that 100s of tiny requests per minute compared to a larger consolidated request is causing the server additional stress. I understand that if the client needs a response it will be slower as there is a lot of waiting from the back and forth. I will consider this and only consolidate when it is appropriate. The more smaller requests per minute, the better user experience, but I don't know what toll it will have on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that a webSocket message will have lower overhead for a given message transmission than sending the same message via an Ajax call because the webSocket connection is already established and because a webSocket message has lower overhead than an HTTP request.

First off, there's always less overhead in sending one larger transmission vs. sending lots of smaller transmissions.  That's just the nature of TCP.  Every TCP packet gets separately processed and acknowledged so sending more of them costs a bit more overhead.  Whether that difference is relevant or significant and worth writing extra code for or worth sacrificing some element of your user experience (because of the delay for batching) depends entirely upon the specifics of a given situation.

Since you've described a situation where your client gets the best experience if there is no delay and no batching of packets, then it seems that what you should do is not implement the batching and test out how your server handles the load with lots of smaller packets when it gets pretty busy.  If that works just fine, then stay with the better user experience.  If you have issues keeping up with the load, then seriously profile your server and find out where the main bottleneck to performance is (you will probably be surprised about where the bottleneck actually is as it is often not where you think it will be - that's why you have to profile and measure to know where to concentrate your energy for improving the scalability).

FYI, due to the implementation of [Nagel's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm) in most implementations of TCP, the TCP stack itself does small amounts of batching for you if you are sending multiple requests fairly closely spaced in time or if sending over a slower link.

It's also possible to implement a dynamic system where as long as your server is able to keep up, you keep with the smaller and more responsive packets, but if your server starts to get busy, you start batching in order to reduce the number of separate transmissions.

Comment: @DanHastings - Did this answer your question?

Comment: Not asker, but it certainly answered mine!